# Как обработать все кнопки одним мтеодом Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нашел такой сайт - https://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/kalkulyator-na-c-sharp-oop.html
Где рассказывают как создать калькулятор на WinForms.
И там для каждой клавишы (от 0 до 9) свой метод.

Возможно как то сделать одним методом все эти клавишы.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да конечно нужно смотреть кто sender. Пребразовать в button и взять его текст.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelNumber.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
 
    CorrectNumber();
}
```